# IE fails to store cookies for some web sites

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP based website. The problem is IE is not storing the cookies for this site. I have cross checked this that the cookies are being saved in the system for other sites: I was able to login to Yahoo, Gmail and so on..... only my site is not working. I tried Mozilla Firefox and Chrome and both are working without any issues.

Usually cookies will be stored to "C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies" and I can see cookies for other websites in this directory but not mine.

This is my url: md1svcvlnx24/wmsdev/

Is there anything wrong in domain name? but I think a domain name can contain numbers.

Thanks,

Comment: `This is my url: md1svcvlnx24/wmsdev/`: Domain name also contains a ***TLD***, doesn't it?

Comment: @Hanky, I don't know what does TLD means. Can you please explain what it is?

Comment: Doesn't your url have to have a .com or a .something at the end?

Comment: Its just like md1svcvlnx24/wmsdev/index.php

Comment: Smells like a local alias to me

Comment: I think so. Because that is the URL that our client have configured in their system

Comment: So that's a local name then its not an international domain name which can be used. For example can I access your server at `http://md1svcvlnx24/wmsdev/index.php` ? no I cant

Comment: Yes you cant. But we do have a network using which we can access our clients instances. I can login to that instance using Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. As I said Cookies are not being saved into the system

Comment: @Hanky, Can you pls suggest something?

Comment: Can someone pls look into this issue? Client is chasing